# Mutiple checkboxes, bound to the same Array in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm starting out with vuejs and a vue grid  at https://jsfiddle.net/kc11/7fqgavvq/

I want to  display the checked row objects in the:

```
    <pre> {{ selected| json}} </pre>
```

area of code,

as in the documentation at http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Checkbox in the "Mutiple checkboxes, bound to the same Array:" example

As you can see when I check 1 checkbox, all are selected. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a few wrong assumptions in your code (mainly in respect to the scope).

You have your `selected` array in your main instance, instead of the `demo-grid` component, where you have your checkboxes:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        searchQuery: '',
        gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
        gridData: [
            {name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity},
            {name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000},
            {name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000},
            {name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000}
        ],
        selected: [] // <- This one
    }
})
```

And there is no `selectAll` method defined on your `demo-grid` component either, even though you reference it in your template:

```
<input @click="selectAll" type="checkbox" v-model="selected" id="{{ entry.name }}" value="{{ entry.name }}"></td>
```

If you thus pass your `selected` property into your `demo-grid`, (and define it in the props), you should be fine:

```
        <demo-grid
            v-bind:data="gridData"
            v-bind:columns="gridColumns"
            v-bind:filter-key="searchQuery"
            v-bind:selected="selected"> <!-- here -->
        </demo-grid>
```

And define a `selectAll` method:

```
methods: {
    ...
    selectAll: function () {
       ...
    }
```

Here you can see a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7fqgavvq/3/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: So reading up at http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing_Data_with_Props , my guess is that because 'selected' was not passed in from the vue instance to the component it was never initialized and this led to errors?

Comment: Yes, because child components don't automatically have access to the properties of their parents (unless they are explicitly passed via `props`). So your `demo-grid` was trying to manipulate a `selected` property that didn't exist (causing errors in the console).

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `selected` key to the component's `data`, not to the main instance of vue.

https://jsfiddle.net/7fqgavvq/4/